# VS code cannot edit in read only editor

Tags: visual-studio-code, terminal, integrated

So I can't edit a running program and when I enabled "whether to run code in integrated terminal" I could no longer run the program as another issue arose "no such file or directory"
I searched and found that this may be related or caused by an extension, but What do I have to do to get around this?
My extensions are:
c/c++
code-runner
Remote-WSL